# How to set the silence timeout for input complete in google speech C#?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

Google speech waits for 3-4 seconds of silence before returning the result. I'd like to decrease this interval.

Android seams to have this options:
RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS
RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS

How can I do this with the C# API? I don't want interims results

Comment: The Android API you've referred to isn't the Google Cloud Speech API as described at https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/. What call are you using at the moment? StreamingRecognitionConfig may be useful to you, but only if you're using streaming calls.

Comment: I'm using streaming calls with StreamingRecognitionConfig. But still no idea how to set the silence timeout. Can you help me please?

Comment: That's not an option on this API, as far as I'm aware. (As far as I know, the Android API is separate.)